# How to extract distinct past values from same metric in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am using the gitlab-ci-pipelines-exporter to track and compare the duration of my pipelines, which are one-time events. However, Prometheus considers only the latest value.

Is there a way to natively extract past pipeline duration or "aggregate" by identical values?
If not, is there a stack/plugin that could handle this?

**Illustration**

[image: Time series]

> Have Prometheus extract values (22:00, 0s) and (22:18, 2s) from the same time series.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although PromQL is described in the documentation as Turing complete at a given time, it does lack the ability to perform historical manipulations save for AVG, LAST and other simple ops that don't count as comparisons.

The workaround I found was to swap Prometheus out for InfluxDB and hope for the best. ;)